# The [autoloader] tag should be synonym for the [autoload] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have tags both for [autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoload) and [autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoloader); both referring to the same concept.

Neither tag is particularly good, since they refer to the same concept in multiple languages; but at least they should be a synonym of each other, since they are used indistinctly.

The [autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoload) tag has both a more more complete tag description and wiki, and more questions tagged (~1400 vs. ~400), so I think it should be the synonym target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoloader) was proposed a synonym to [autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoload) by Wouter J way back on Jun 15 '13, but was never approved. Surprisingly, it wasn't voted on at all. I approved the synonym proposal, that is:

[autoloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoloader) (× 397) → [autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoload) (× 1466)

I'll wait for a few days before merging the two tags, in case there are any issues with the synonym.